# Finalizar laço de repetição Repita do Visualg

Tags: visualg

Quando utilizamos o `repita` junto com o `ate` no final do bloco, devemos utilizar também o `fimrepita`? Se não, quando utilizamos este?

```
algoritmo "semnome"
var
   t,n,i,m:inteiro
inicio
   i<-0
   repita
      escreval ("entre com a nota")
      leia (N)
      escreval ("entre com a nota")
      leia (M)
      t<-(n+m)\2
      escreval ("a media do aluno foi:",t)
      i<-i+1
   ate i=5
fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 2):

O `fimrepita` é usado quando não há nenhuma condição de parada pré-definida, como o `ate`. Ou seja, quando ele repete até que ocorra uma condição de parada, como abaixo:

```
var x: inteiro
x <- 0
repita
    x <- x + 1
    se x = 10 entao
        interrompa
fimrepita
```

Ele serve para definir até onde vai o bloco de código do seu comando repita. Mas, quando você utiliza o comando `ate`, não é necessário usar o `fimrepita`.

## Referência

- [A linguagem de programação VisuAlg - UFPR](http://eletrica.ufpr.br/%7Erogerio/visualg/Help/linguagem3.htm)